ConsolaApp C# ERROR "El proyecto no sabe como ejecutar el perfil con el nombre y el comando IIS Express"
He creado servicios api en un proyecto en consola por requerimiento por lo que al levantar en IIS Express me sale el error


Y por qué de consola??? por qué no creas un proyecto API??

el requerimiento lo solicitado

Estaría top 3 entre los requerimientos más extraños que he visto. Un proyecto API es un proyecto de consola que viene configurado (a través de su template) para levantar un servidor web.

El alcance es subir el proyecto al cloud

Mi solución fue agregar un perfil con los siguientes datos {
"exclude": [
"/bin",
"/bower_components",
"/jspm_packages",
"/node_modules",
"/obj",
"/platforms"
],
"profiles": {
"FldOps.MailingJob": {
"commandName": "Project",
"commandLineArgs": "--port 7165",
"launchBrowser": false
}
}
}
